# Mobile robotic arm camera position

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm, computer-vision, cameras

I'm working on my graduation project which is a mobile robotic arm that performs pick and place tasks.

I wanted to know the possible ways to mount the camera where i can reach the desired destination and for the robot arm to be able to perform the pick and place task.

Based on what I've seen, most people mount the camera on a fixed platform pointing down, but I prefer it to be mounted to the robot. Do I have to mount it looking down? Because i figured this way i can only use it for the picking and placing part, not the robot reaching the destination too.

Comment: HI Osama, welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange. Reviewing your question it does not meet our requirements for having a specific answerable question. Without more details there's not going to be a clear answer which will solve your problem. Except maybe "No, you don't have to". Please update your question to be less open ended.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your idea.
I also did a similar project, and I was satisfied with the camera mounted to the end effector. Thus I could see wether the gripper is really gripping an object ot not, and also the area where it will place it.

Another advantage of mounting the camera to a robot is that you can also explore your surroundings with it e.g. creating a point cloud map, or just update it...
This is really depends on you.

Search for similar projects and compare it with your options.